# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cada perfil tenga N número de mascotas? Cada perfil debe tener mascotas diferentes

Tags: html, jquery, html5, local-storage

Si estoy agregando perfiles, mascotas y medicinas desde inputs, pero necesito que al seleccionar un perfil pueda acceder a sus mascotas.

```
     <script>
            //Aquí se crean 2 perfiles con local storage.

            if (store.get("total-de-perfiles") == null) {
                //Crear perfil 1:
                store.set("perfil1", {
                    nombre: "Pedrito"
                    , numerodemascotas: 2
                    , correo: "pedrito@gmail.com"
                });
                //Crear perfil 2:
                store.set("perfil2", {
                    nombre: "María"
                    , numerodemascotas: 3
                    , correo: "maria@gmail.com"
                });
                store.set("total-de-perfiles", 2);
            }

            //Agregar los perfiles (si es que hay)
            desplegarperfiles = function () {
                var totperfiles = store.get("total-de-perfiles");
                //Borrar el contenido de perdiles-container
                $("#perfiles-container").html("");
                for (var i = 1; i <= totperfiles; i++) {
                    var perfil = store.get("perfil" + i);
                    $("#perfiles-container").append("<div class='botonesPerfiles boton'>PERFIL " + i + "<br>" + perfil.nombre + "</div>");
                }
            }
            desplegarperfiles();

            //Crear un nuevo perfil obteniendo datos de inputs.
            $("#crear-perfil").click(function () {
                var totperfiles = store.get("total-de-perfiles");
                totperfiles++;
                store.set("total-de-perfiles", totperfiles);
                var nombreinput = $("#perfil-nombre").val();
                var numinput = $("#perfil-numero-mascotas").val();
                var emailinput = $("#perfil-email").val();
                store.set("perfil" + totperfiles, {
                    nombre: nombreinput
                    , numerodemascotas: numinput
                    , correo: emailinput
                });

                //Agregar el perfil a la página de perfiles...
                desplegarperfiles();
                //Ir a la página de perfiles:
                $("section").hide();
                $("#perfiles").show();
            });

// A partir de aquí es lo mismo tanto para Mascotas como para medicinas.



            <!-- Mascotas -->
            if (store.get("total-de-mascotas") == null) {
                //Crear perfil 1:
                store.set("mascota1", {
                    nombremascota: "Pirulin"
                    , edaddemascota: "3"
                    , pesodemascota: "2"
                    , tipodemascota: "Perro"
                });
                //Crear perfil 2:
                store.set("mascota2", {
                    nombremascota: "Piripicho"
                    , edaddemascota: "3"
                    , pesodemascota: "2"
                    , tipodemascota: "Gato"
                });
                store.set("total-de-mascotas", 2);
            }
            //Agregar los perfiles (si es que hay)
            desplegarmismascotas = function () {
                var totmascotas = store.get("total-de-mascotas");
                //Borrar el contenido de perdiles-container
                $("#mascotas-container").html("");
                for (var i = 1; i <= totmascotas; i++) {
                    var mascota = store.get("mascota" + i);
                    console.log(mascota);
                    console.log(i);
                    $("#mascotas-container").append("<div class='botonesMisMascotas boton'>MASCOTA " + i + "<br>" + mascota.nombremascota + "</div>");
                }
            }
            desplegarmismascotas();
            //Crear un nuevo perfil
            $("#crear-mascota").click(function () {
                var totmascotas = store.get("total-de-mascotas");
                totmascotas++;
                store.set("total-de-mascotas", totmascotas);
                var nombremascotainput = $("#nombre-mascota").val();
                var edadinput = $("#edad-mascota").val();
                var pesoinput = $("#peso-mascota").val();
                var tiposelect = $("#tipo-mascota").val();
                store.set("mascota" + totmascotas, {
                    nombremascota: nombremascotainput
                    , edaddemascota: edadinput
                    , pesodemascota: pesoinput
                    , tipodemascota: tiposelect
                });
                //Agregar el perfil a la página de perfiles...
                desplegarmismascotas();
                //Ir a la página de perfiles:
                $("section").hide();
                $("#mismascotas").show();
            });

            <!-- Medicinas -->
            if (store.get("total-de-medicinas") == null) {
                //Crear perfil 1:
                store.set("medicina1", {
                    nombremedicina: "Flanax"
                    , horariomedicina: "0"
                    , dosismedicina: "200g"
                });
                //Crear perfil 2:
                store.set("medicina2", {
                    nombremedicina: "Flanax"
                    , horariomedicina: "0"
                    , dosismedicina: "200g"
                });
                store.set("total-de-medicinas", 2);
            }
            //Agregar los perfiles (si es que hay)
            desplegarmismedicinas = function () {
                var totmedicinas = store.get("total-de-medicinas");
                //Borrar el contenido de perdiles-container
                $("#medicinas-container").html("");
                for (var i = 1; i <= totmedicinas; i++) {
                    var medicina = store.get("medicina" + i);
                    console.log(medicina);
                    console.log(i);
                    $("#medicinas-container").append("<div class='botonesMisMedicinas boton'>MEDICINA " + i + "<br>" + medicina.nombremedicina + "</div>");
                }
            }
            desplegarmismedicinas();
            //Crear un nuevo perfil
            $("#crear-medicina").click(function () {
                var totmedicinas = store.get("total-de-medicinas");
                totmedicinas++;
                store.set("total-de-medicinas", totmedicinas);
                var nombremedicinainput = $("#nombre-medicina").val();
                var horariomedicinainput = $("#horario-medicina").val();
                var dosismedicinainput = $("#dosis-medicina").val();
                store.set("mascota" + totmascotas, {
                    nombremedicina: nombremedicinainput
                    , horariomedicina: horariomedicinainput
                    , dosismedicina: dosismedicinainput
                });
                //Agregar el perfil a la página de perfiles...
                desplegarmedicinas();
                //Ir a la página de perfiles:
                $("section").hide();
                $("#mismaedicinas").show();
            });


        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Por qué no documentas un poco el código? Explícanos qué quieres hacer, cómo y que has intentado para hacerlo.

Comment: @AntoTGa claro, una disculpa soy nuevo publicando aquí, ahorita lo edito.

Comment: Perfil de persona tiene "numero de mascotas" pero no tiene ninguna relacion con SUS mascotas por lo tanto nunca vas a verlas

Comment: La pregunta no solo es poco clara, creo que también tiene etiquetas erróneas. ¿Que tiene que ver tu duda con css por ejemplo?